# KKT conditions for nonsmooth convex problems

Tags: optimization, convex-analysis, convex-optimization, karush-kuhn-tucker, non-smooth-optimization

What are the KKT conditions for a non-smooth convex function?
Is the vanishing gradient of Lagrangian, replaced by $0$ in sub-differential of the Lagrangian, and all other things remain the same?

I suppose that will give necessary and sufficient optimality condition assuming duality gap is zero, right?

Comment: Just to clarify, the KKT conditions are necessary and sufficient only when some *constraint qualifications* hold.

Comment: Thanks my statement is not precise. I will fix it now.

Comment: At least in first order, I think it is true. You can see [this resource (Slide #7)](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~ggordon/10725-F12/slides/16-kkt.pdf) for verification.

Comment: That is useful. Thank you Nitish.

Comment: @Nitish What do you mean by "At least in first order"? Isn't the statement in the question simply true?

Comment: @littleO First order KKT conditions versus higher order conditions.